# Avro schema with logicalType can't be used with latest confluent-kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

We are using kafka with avro schemas and schema registry set to `FULL` compatibility. Our schemas use `logicalType` fields, for example:

```
{
  "name": "MyRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "created_at",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

This works fine with the pretty old version of `confluent-kafka` we are using, as it depends on `avro-python3` 1.8. However, recent `confluent-kafka` depends on `avro-python3` 1.10, and message serialization fails with `TypeError: unhashable type: 'mappingproxy'`

[I've opened a PR to fix the issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/pull/1208) but it's not getting much attention.

Assuming it will not be merged, what other options do I have to upgrade to a recent `confluent-kafka`?

The only solution I see is getting rid of the `logicalType`, but that will be an incompatible schema change, so I either give up on the `FULL` compatibility or use a different topic bound to a different schema.

And even if the above works, then I have to manually convert millis to timestamps, which is quite a change across our codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema isn't valid Avro. The [documentation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Unions) states that *“when a default value is specified for a record field whose type is a union, the type of the default value must match the **first** element of the union”*. For your field `created_at` “`null`” is the only valid default value, otherwise you'll have to define your schema as

```json
...
    {
      "name": "created_at",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        },
        "null"
      ],
      "default": 1
    }
...
```

this would have an default of the January 1st, 1970 (actually 1 millisecond after midnight), which might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for catching it, I edited the question. Unfortunately that was not enough to solve our problem